# glob not picking up some files?

Tags: php, mp3, glob

```
$files = glob("*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++){
    $file = $files[$i];
    echo "$file<br />";
}
```

I'm trying to display all the files in a directory, this is picking up the .php files i have in this directory but it isn't finding mp3 files. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

May be this works :)

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++){
```

Why don't you use foreach

```
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```